# Worker role with java example in Azure

Tags: java, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-eventhub

I couldn't find any good example of a worker role for java on azure cloud.
I am writing an amqp publisher jms application for event hubs to simulate large amount of data as a stream. I wanted to run this application on cloud and scale it to produce data according to changing needs.

Comment: I believe this is the best information we have on this specific topic https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Interoperability/Java-Applications-in-Windows-Azure-Cloud-Services-using-Eclipse you might also consider looking here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/java/ as we have other ways to run java apps in Azure and that utilize newer services instead of cloud services

Answer (score 1):

As I known, Azure plugins for Eclipse is to support the features of Cloud Services few years ago, so you can search many resources like the channel9 videos as @Micah_MSFT said. But now, I found it has removed these features for Cloud Services after I tried to install the plugin in my Eclipse.

There are two old blogs which may be helpful in your scenario.

1. [Deploying Java Applications in Azure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mariok/2011/01/05/deploying-java-applications-in-azure/)
2. [Installing Java Runtime in Azure Cloud Services with Chocolatey](http://www.rajinders.com/2015/07/06/installing-java-runtime-in-azure-cloud-services-with-chocolatey/)

Meanwhile, `Microsoft Azure Service Fabric is the next-generation cloud application platform for highly scalable, highly reliable distributed applications`, that can be instead of Cloud Service, you can refer to the offical document [Learn about the differences between Cloud Services and Service Fabric before migrating applications.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cloud-services-migration-differences) to compare them, and there is a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-create-java-app) for Java.

Just per my experience, as workaround, there are other simple services which be suitable for generating data by Java on Azure cloud, and that can be scaled.

1. For using App Services, Continuous WebJobs can be scaled with the number of WebApp instances.
2. On Azure, `Use Batch to run large-scale parallel and high-performance computing (HPC) applications efficiently in the cloud.` So you can write a Java Application to produce data and run on Batch service parallelly. There is an offical [sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/azure-batch-samples/) in Java which you can refer to.